# How can i search through a json api using angularjs/ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How can i check if the id that i get from the url is equal to any of the ids in the json api here is my code

```
      .controller('PlayAod', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
    $scope.title = 'Sample Company';
    $scope.apiusername = 'hoy';
    $scope.apipassword = '076fdf74936ebae00e7949a80f61f985';
    $scope.aodid = $stateParams.ahls;
    $scope.stream = "";

    $http.get('http://tvstartup.biz/mng-channel/vpanel/api/audios.php?user=' + $scope.apiusername + '&pass=' + $scope.apipassword).success(function (data) {
        $scope.aodhls = data.audios;
        if (data.audios.id == $scope.aodid) {
            $scope.stream = date.audios.hls_stream;
        }
    });
$scope.play = function() {
      window.cndStream.play($scope.stream);
    }
      $scope.pause = function() {
      window.cndStream.pause();
    }



    }])
```

please help if you have any questions post in comments

Answer (score 0):

As I have experience with your problem from another question, I will add context for other users that your $http request here returns an array of objects, and each of the objects has a property named 'id'.

Assuming that you are trying to track down the particular object within the array of which `object.id == $scope.aodid`, you can search over the array until the comparative proves true.  One such example would be:

```
// Inside of $http.get success function
var audioList = data.audios;

for(var audio of audioList) {
    if(audio.id == $scope.aodid) {
        // Oh, joy this is the one I want!
        // Perform some magic...

        // Or maybe in your case...
        $scope.stream = audio.hls_stream;

        // Dont forget to stop searching...
        break;
    }   
}
```

A potentially better solution would be to provide the ID in the query such that you only get back what you want and don't have to iterate a list, however I am infering a bit as to what you are ultimately trying to do.